# The fist column's update of a while loop that calculates accumulative values is giving me the total instead

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am calculating the accumulative values of the columns that end in 'YtD' using their counterparts that don't end in 'YtD' through a while loop (Bajas -> BajasYtD, Headcount -> HeadcountYtD, and so on and so forth).

The problem is that the first column is giving me the grand total and not the accumulative value per each passing iteration.

I tried reverting the order of updating the values and it gives me same thing but now with the "HeadcountYtD" column.

The result is:

```
id          Periodo                                            Bajas                  Headcount              Rango                  Rot                    BajasYtD               HeadcountYtD           RangoYtD               RotYtD
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1           2018-01                                            276                    328453                 28                     0.0235284804827479     3756                   328453                 0                      0
2           2018-02                                            336                    336807                 28                     0.0279329111330822     3756                   665260                 0                      0
3           2018-03                                            325                    337985                 28                     0.0269242717872095     3756                   1003245                0                      0
4           2018-04                                            420                    342765                 28                     0.0343092206030371     3756                   1346010                0                      0
5           2018-05                                            415                    344723                 28                     0.0337082237042495     3756                   1690733                0                      0
6           2018-06                                            315                    347945                 28                     0.0253488338674216     3756                   2038678                0                      0
7           2018-07                                            321                    351110                 28                     0.025598815186124      3756                   2389788                0                      0
8           2018-08                                            367                    353390                 28                     0.0290783553581029     3756                   2743178                0                      0
9           2018-09                                            329                    357692                 28                     0.0257540006486027     3756                   3100870                0                      0
10          2018-10                                            337                    360974                 28                     0.0261403868422657     3756                   3461844                0                      0
11          2018-11                                            315                    245736                 19                     0.0243554058013478     3756                   3707580                0                      0
```

My code is:

```
USE DBDMS
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TablaBajas') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #TablaRotPeriodo
END
CREATE TABLE #TablaRotPeriodo
(id int identity(1,1)
,Periodo varchar(50)
,Bajas float
,Headcount float
,Rango float
,Rot float
,BajasYtD float
,HeadcountYtD float
,RangoYtD float
,RotYtD float)
INSERT INTO #TablaRotPeriodo
SELECT TPO_CPeriodo AS Periodo
,SUM(ROT_IBAJA)                 AS Bajas
,SUM(ROT_IHCOUNT)               AS Headcount
,COUNT(DISTINCT T.TPO_CFecha)   AS Rango        
,SUM(ROT_IBAJA)/(SUM(ROT_IHCOUNT)/COUNT(DISTINCT T.TPO_CFecha)) AS Rot
,0                              AS BajasYtD 
,0                              AS HeadcountYtD
,0                              AS RangoYtD
,0                              as RotYtD
FROM TH_Rotacion R
INNER JOIN TD_Tiempo T ON R.TPO_KFECHA=T.TPO_KFecha
WHERE T.TPO_CFecha>=@vDiaiYtD
AND T.TPO_CFecha<=@vDiaf
GROUP BY TPO_CPeriodo
ORDER BY TPO_CPeriodo asc

SELECT * FROM #TablaRotPeriodo

DECLARE @cnt int =1;
WHILE (@cnt <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TablaRotPeriodo))
BEGIN
    UPDATE #TablaRotPeriodo
        SET BajasYtD        =(SELECT SUM(Bajas)     FROM #TablaRotPeriodo WHERE id<=@cnt)
    UPDATE #TablaRotPeriodo
        SET HeadcountYtD    =(SELECT SUM(Headcount) FROM #TablaRotPeriodo WHERE id<=@cnt)
WHERE [id]=@cnt
SET @cnt=@cnt+1
END

SELECT * FROM #TablaRotPeriodo
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and the logic for the columns is what is really needed for a good question.

Comment: Which columns are you trying to get the accumulated values for?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the acumulated values for all the columns that have the suffix YtD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single `select` and `apply`:

```
with t as (
      <your aggregation query here>
     )
select t.*, tsum.*
from t cross apply
     (select sum(tsum.bajas) as t.bajasytd,
             sum(tsum.headcount) as headcountytd,
             . . .
      from t tsum
      where tsum.periodo <= t.periodo
     ) tsum;
```

A `while` loop is not necessary.

In SQL Server 2012, this would be simpler and more efficient using window functions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your query correctly, you are trying to get the cumulative sum of `Bajas` and `HeadCount` over time. If that is the case, this windowing method should work:

```
 SELECT id, periodo, 
           Bajas, SUM(Bajas) OVER(ORDER BY periodo ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS BajasYTD,
           HeadCount, SUM(HeadCount) OVER(ORDER BY periodo ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS HeadCountYTD
    FROM table
```